# Can't correctly style nested lists in mobile menu view

Tags: css

I'm trying to complete a mobile responsive menu in pure CSS that has dropdowns. My problem is, I can't get the mobile styles of the menu to display as you would expect, that is, a simple list with lines separating each list item with all levels visible (including indentation where sub-menus are applicable). As you can see in this demo, where the nested ul starts, it screens off the other menu items. How would I fix this? Thanks.

Demo:

```css
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 16px 20px 16px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgb(30, 30, 30);  
}


.menu-left li{
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  padding-right: 32px;
}

#main-nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#main-nav li {
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#main-nav li:hover .submenu > li {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
}

.submenu li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.submenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.submenu li {
  position: relative;
}

.submenu li:hover .submenu-2 li {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-2 li {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 120px;
}

.arrow {
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  font-size: 12px;
}

/*
Media -------------------------------------------
*/

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  #main-nav {
    display: block; 
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-top: 1px solid MediumTurquoise;
  }

  li:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
  }

  #main-nav a {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #main-nav ul {
    display: block;
  }

  #main-nav li {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid MediumTurquoise;
    position: static;
  }

  .nav-menu-border {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .submenu {
    display: block;
    position: static;
  }

  .submenu li {
    display: initial;
    position: static;
    top: auto;
  }
  
  .submenu-2 {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    top: auto;
  }

  .submenu-2 li {
    display: initial;
  }

  #main-nav li:hover .submenu > li { 
    /* reset the hover styles to disable hover effect */
    display: initial;
    top: auto;
  }

  .submenu li:hover .submenu-2 li {
    /* reset the hover styles to disable hover effect */
    display: initial;
  }

  .submenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav" class="menu">

  <ul class="menu-left">
    <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="color:red;">THREE</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">SIX<span class="arrow">&#9658;</span></a>
          <ul class="submenu-2">
            <li><a href="#">SEVEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EIGHT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NINE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEN</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ELEVEN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TWELVE</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu-right">
    <li><a href="#">THIRTEEN</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>

<h2>Drag the screen width slider to see the mobile menu </h2>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "screens off the other menu".

Comment: I noticed the UL under list item "Three" has a huge height that spans all the way down to list item "Twelve". It could be much more than that, it's just that I can't really figure out what is going wrong, but the whole thing is meant to look like the first couple and last couple of list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do lots of changes. I won't go into detail for each change, but I'll explain what the main changes I did:

- **Display** - Flex is very flexible (got it?). You can change the direction to display to column instead of a row, so it helps you spread your layout responsively in this case much easier.
- **Padding & Border** - I moved these rules to the `a` tags that are inside of the `li` tag because I wanted the `li` to be responsible only for display behavior. Plus, since you have lots of nested li, it just makes more sense no to use these rules, because you'll get additional padding and border.
- **Indention** - There's a rule called `text-indent` which does what you needed. Instead of adding custom padding from the start-side, you can use `text-indent` rule, and it will take care of the indention.

You can see for yourself the results:

```css
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 16px 20px 16px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgb(30, 30, 30);  
}


.menu-left li{
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  padding-right: 32px;
}

#main-nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#main-nav li {
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#main-nav li:hover .submenu > li {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
}

.submenu li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.submenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.submenu li {
  position: relative;
}

.submenu li:hover .submenu-2 li {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-2 li {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 120px;
}

.arrow {
  margin-left: 8px;
  color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  font-size: 12px;
}

/*
Media -------------------------------------------
*/

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  #main-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-top: 1px solid MediumTurquoise;
  }

  li:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
  }

  #main-nav a {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid MediumTurquoise;
    display: block;
  }
  
  #main-nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #main-nav li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: static;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .nav-menu-border {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .submenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: static;
    text-indent: 10px
  }

  .submenu li {
    display: block;
    position: static;
  }
  
  .submenu-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    text-indent: 20px;
  }

  .submenu-2 li {
    display: block;
  }

  .submenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav" class="menu">

  <ul class="menu-left">
    <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="color:red;">THREE</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">SIX<span class="arrow">&#9658;</span></a>
          <ul class="submenu-2">
            <li><a href="#">SEVEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EIGHT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NINE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEN</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ELEVEN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TWELVE</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu-right">
    <li><a href="#">THIRTEEN</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>

<h2>Drag the screen width slider to see the mobile menu </h2>
```

PS:

You may consider styling by the mobile first approach. It'll make your code much more manageable.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I agree, styling mobile first would have been a much easier approach.